# Cordova Facebook Connect - can't get userID

Tags: facebook, cordova

I added to phonegap app Facebook Connect,
It works fine and generates Access Token, But when I'm trying to get the userID the value is
**"Undenified"**
my function:

```
 FB.init({
        appId: "************",
        nativeInterface:CDV.FB,
        xfbml: true,
        useCachedDialogs: false,
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        oauth: true
    });
    //alert("Init Done");
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {               
            if (response.status == 'connected') {                  
                Token = response.authResponse.accessToken;// This one is Good!                   
                userid = response.authResponse.userID;// This one is Bad                  

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following and it works fine:

```
FB.api('/me', {}, function (response) {
    fbuserid = response.userid;
});
```

This gives you the user data. You can also pass the scope just to get what you want like email, userid, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the keys to see what is stored

```
for (var key in response.authResponse) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(response.authResponse[key]);
}
```